# How do you remove a fieldcontain border when using KO "if" binding?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

JSFiddle is here (need to debug this on mobile to get the bottom border btw):

http://jsfiddle.net/npgrier/6p3WV/3/

Change the `this.showOptions = ko.observable(true);` line to pass in false to the observable.  The elements get removed from the page, but the bottom border is still there.  Is there a way to make sure this border gets removed when the elements are also removed from the DOM?

Comment: not seeing the bottom border when I run it...what browser/version/os are you using?

Comment: You have to do it on a mobile device, if running it from the desktop, it won't display the bottom border.

Comment: You can move the if binding outside of your second div, it also removes the border: http://jsfiddle.net/q4tVL/

Comment: @nemesv with the code base that we have we have a little more work to do than just that, but it's close enough for me to accept if you want to post it as the answer.

Comment: This has nothing to do with field contain, it's the input itself. JQM wraps `input` with a div, it has a `.ui-input`. Your code hides `input` but leaves its parent div visible. So you need a way to hide the div not the input, or inject it dynamically.

Comment: Check the difference here http://jsfiddle.net/wdBef/

Comment: @Omar correct, this was a simpler problem than what I thought it was.  As @nemesv suggested moving the `if` binding outside of the second div answers the question.  I didn't realize that `fieldcontain` left a border there on an empty div when we implemented the code, now I know a better way to do it.

Comment: @Omar, excellent example! That makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that even if you set your observables to false your `data-role="fieldcontain"` divs still remain in the DOM because KO will only remove their contents but not the `div` themselves.

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" data-bind="if: showOptions">
   ...
</div>
<div data-bind="if: showTextBox" data-role="fieldcontain">
   ...
</div>
```

So these divs are your "border".

One solution is to use the container less syntax of the `if` binding and wrap your div with the `if`:

```
<!-- ko if: showTextBox -->
    <div data-bind="" data-role="fieldcontain">
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

So if you set `showTextBox` now to false KO will remove the whole div so your border goes away.